# Unexpected Python print behavior

Tags: python, python-2.x

When I try this code in Python 2.7.3:

```
names = ["Paul", "Mary", "Susan"]
names.sort()

def valuate(string):
    print ord('A')
    return sum(ord(s) for s in string)

i = 1
for name in names:
    print i, name, valuate(name)
    i += 1
```

I expect the output:

```
65
1 Mary 409
65
2 Paul 402
65
3 Susan 522
```

But instead I get:

```
1 Mary 65
409
2 Paul 65
402
3 Susan 65
522
```

It seems the `print` statement outputs the `i` and `name` values before calling the function. Is that so? Why?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537355/python-order-in-which-functions-in-print-statement-are-called. In Python 3.x, because `print` became a *function*, it works the way *this* OP expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surprise you're encountering is that the [`print` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) prints out each of the expressions it is given before evaluating the next one. That is, a statement like `print A, B, C` is equivalent to:

```
print A, # note, the trailing comma suppresses the newline
print B,
print C
```

As you'd expect from separate statements, A gets written out before B or C is evaluated.

That surprise is perhaps part of the reason that Python 3 has done away with the `print` statement in favor of a builtin `print` function which behaves more like you expect (all of its arguments are evaluated before the function runs).

In Python 2, you can get the Python 3 style `print` if you want using a `future` import:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Indeed, my conceptual model of the print function was that all arguments are evaluated before the print occurs. But now I understand the way it executes and also how it will behave in the future.

Answer (score 6):

It's not just the `print` statement, it's the function call.

```
print i, name, valuate(name)
```

Prints `i`, then `name`, then calls `valuate` which prints 65 (and a new line) then on return the `print` statement continues to print the return value (and another newline).

Answer (score 4):

The sequence of events is as follows:

```
print i,
print name,
val = valuate(name) # prints ord('A')
print val
```

This is confirmed by looking at the bytecodes generated for `print i, name, valuate(name)`:

```
 11          19 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             22 PRINT_ITEM          
             23 LOAD_FAST                1 (name)
             26 PRINT_ITEM          
             27 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (valuate)
             30 LOAD_FAST                1 (name)
             33 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             36 PRINT_ITEM          
             37 PRINT_NEWLINE
```

I don't know if this evaluation order is guaranteed (a quick search didn't reveal anything). I definitely wouldn't rely on it, and therefore wouldn't write code like this.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple. Your print statement evaluates the arguments lazily. It prints i first, then name, and then it calls valuate. Valuate prints 65. Then your print statement prints the result of valuate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a small ',' would make things a lot more simple to grasp.

```
names = ["Paul", "Mary", "Susan"]
names.sort()

def valuate(string):
    print ord('A'),
    return sum(ord(s) for s in string)

i = 1
for name in names:
    print i, name, valuate(name)
    i += 1
```

Now that outputs:

```
1 Mary 65 409
2 Paul 65 402
3 Susan 65 522
```

The comma after `print` makes it not to print a new line character  at the end. So now you can see that `valuate` first prints the `ord('A')` and then returns the output for the outer print. (I also indented the `i += 1` line)